# Equivalent sets

Tags: real-analysis

Can I say that two subsets of real line with same measure and same boundary are equivalent? By equivalence of two sets $A$ and $B$ we mean there exists a bijective map between them.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $C$ denote the Cantor-set, then the sets $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} \cup C$ are both null-sets and have the same boundary $\mathbb{R}$, but there is no bijection between these two because $C$ is uncountable.